# How to check if the message contains a mention in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

We have a globalchat funcion in our bot and we don't want people to mention other people or everyone through it, so we disabled "@" symbol in messages, but now if you type "@ Hello World!", it will return and your message will not be sent.

```py
                if "@" in message.content:
                    return
```

How do I check if there is a mention in that message? message.mention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discord mentions are not really processed like that, a raw user mention looks something like this `<@{id_here}>` and a nick mention looks like this `<@!{id_here}>`.

You could make a simple regex, but the `Message` object already has the `mentions` attribute, which returns a list of `discord.User`/`discord.Member` instances:

```py
if message.mentions: # If the list is not empty
    return
```

#### Reference:

- [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions)

Comment: Thank you! That really helped me out. I tried `message.mention` because it seemed more logical, but I can understand that too.