# How to check if the user mentioned someone or just wrote gibberish

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am coding a command that asks person x to "bruh" a target. So basically when the command is run it asks who the user wants to bruh. Then after the user mentions the target, it proceeds to write a message to person x saying that the user wants them to "bruh" the target. So what I'm trying to verify is that if the user actually mentioned someone or just wrote gibberish. This all sounds a little confusing but I'm sure the code will help.

```
@client.command()
async def bruh(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Who do you want to bruh?')

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    target_id = msg.content


    if msg.content == target_id:
        await ctx.send("<@!person_x_id>, <@!%s>" % ctx.author.id + " wants you to bruh " + target_id)
    else:
        await ctx.send("bruh that guy's not in the server")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the message contains a mention in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054854/how-to-check-if-the-message-contains-a-mention-in-discord-py)

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand that. Are you saying that there should be a list of all the members in the server and then see if the message (user mentioned) is in the list?

Comment: Try using `msg.mentions`

Comment: Wait never mind. I got it! Thanks a bunch!